# Why my own IP address has been blocked from accessing the site when I have added it as Allow entry in iis7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I am running my asp.net website on localhost. My internal network IP address is something like 192.168.x.x and the static IP address is diff and is same for all client PCs in my office. Now, I added this internal network IP address and the static IP address in IP Address and Domian Restrictions" module in II7 as "Allow Entry" and I set "Access for unspecified clients" as "Deny".

Now I am unable to run my website on local!! It says :-

```
"HTTP Error 403.6 - Forbidden The IP address from which you are browsing is not permitted to access the requested Web site."
```

IIS is obviously considering my PC's IP as one of the "UnSpecified clients" whose entry is denied. But when I HAVE added my network's static IP address AND my private network address in Allow Entry then why is it not letting me access the website??

How do you block IP addresses in iis7 if not like this? I need only 2 IP addresses to access my site..not ANY other.

Comment: localhost may be expected to be a loopback address, e.g. 127.0.0.1

Comment: Did you try to add 127.0.0.1 to the allowed list of IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

If running the client and server on the same computer, it will use the `localhost` loopback address when making requests. The `localhost` name always resolves to the IP address `127.0.0.1`. Add that to your Allow list and you will have access.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the module IpRestrictionModule. This tells us that you have a setting that denies certain IP addresses. Please check the IP and domain restrictions in IIS Manager.

If you cannot figure out what is wrong, please paste all entries of "configuration/system.webServer/security/ipSecurity"  in the applicationHost.config. This helps us identify what is wrong.